# How to create two separate git repository in the same folder?

Tags: php, git, drupal

I have a git repository linked to a folder in my pc containing some files and some directory of a Drupal site. Now, i want to redistribute my code, but i want some folders to remain out of the 'public' repository, but stored in a 'private' repository.
Something like

```
Drupal Directory (git repository)
| -- file1.php
| -- file2.html
| -- modules
| -- sites
```

Now, i have a repository containing the whole stuff, but ignoring 'sites' (contains a .gitignore), and a i want the data of 'sites' to be stored in a different repository (so to have it private) WITHOUT moving the directory because changing the directory position means the site will not work. All solution, with subtree, for example, were putting the 'sites' directory out of the main repository directory.

I need this for, actually, the 'sites' directory is not on git and so i don't have an online backup, but i need it not to be accessed by other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use **git submodules**. Let's that you have a library that is on repository B. Your program is on repository A and uses this library and needs to have access to all its source code. To keep this library separated from your own software you add repository B as a submodule of repository A. So each time you make changes on the library, the repository B will take care of track it, the same with your own software.

Of course each repository can have its own configuration, repository A can be private while B can be public, so everyone can get the changes you make in the library while your own software remains closed source.

Comment: Exactly what i was searching for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could consider:

- [splitting the repo in two](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two), isolating `sites` in its own repo
- referencing site as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)** in the Drupal repo (the path will be `sites`, as it is now)

There have been instances of [Drupal deployment involving submodules](http://randyfay.com/content/drupal-deployment-git-submodules) before.